# PHP/MYSQL CSV Import while fgetcsv Loop vs LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, csv

i have a CSV on a external WebSite and want to get the content to a mysql DB. I tried it with:

```
$fp = fopen($file,"r");
$row = fgetcsv($fp,0,"|");
while ( $row = fgetcsv($fp,0,"|") ){
    foreach ($row as &$value) {
        $value = "\"". $value . "\"";
    }                           
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`ProductID`, `ProductCategory`, `Deeplink`, `ProductName`, `ImageURL`, `ImageURL2`, `ImageURL3`, `ImageURL4`, `ProductDescription`, `BrandName`, `Price`, `PreviousPrice`, `AvailableSizes`, `Color`, `EAN`, `Gender`, `Product_Quantity`, `Stylekey`, `Best_Performer`) VALUES("."". implode(",", $row) . ")";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);  
};
```

So far on the first impression this is working fine, but slowly. Slowly is no Problem. There's a lot of time to do that. The main Problem is, that there are not all rows from the csv in the db. i can't find differences between the imported rows and the ones which are not imported.

So i tried it with Load Data Infile.

First Download the csv like that:

```
file_put_contents("debug.csv", fopen("http://domain.com/debug.csv", 'r'))
```

And then:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'debug.csv'
        INTO TABLE aboutyou
        CHARACTER SET 'utf8' 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
        IGNORE 1 LINES 
        (ProductID, ProductCategory, Deeplink, ProductName, ImageURL, ImageURL2, ImageURL3, ImageURL4, ProductDescription, BrandName, Price, PreviousPrice, AvailableSizes, Color, EAN, Gender, Product_Quantity, Stylekey, Best_Performer)
        SET ID = NULL
        ";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

On my local Machine the "Load Data Local Infile" works great. All Data will be imported and really fast. On the Webserver the download Works but the Load Data Local Infile (with or without "Local") isn't working and and output no error.

Comment: LOCAL works only if your server and your client both have been configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld was started with --local-infile=0, LOCAL does not work.

Comment: You say "output no error" but are you explicitly checking MySQLi for errors? `echo mysqli_error($link);` to check.  It's common for shared hosts to disable `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: I have checked the mysqli Errors. mysqli_query($link, "DELETE FROM table"); is working fine. With LOAD DATA INFILE i get: "Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" and with LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE i get "The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version"